# how to exec ffmpeg command java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute this command:

```
c:\ffmpeg\ -i c:\ffmpeg\bin\input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -vf scale=480:-1 -y c:\ffmpeg\bin\output.mp4
```

and I'm getting

> Cannot run program "197": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm guessing it's something to do with the path(s). Can you help me convert to convert a video file by only scalling it using `ffmpeg`:

my code:

```
try {
    String command=gui.jTextField2.getText().trim();
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\ffmpeg\ -i c:\ffmpeg\bin\input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -vf scale=480:-1 -y c:\ffmpeg\bin\output.mp4"); //Whatever you want to execute

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            proc.getInputStream()));
    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        gui.textArea1.append("\n"+e.getMessage());
    }
    while (read.ready()) {
        gui.textArea1.append("\n"+read.readLine());
    }
}catch(IOException ex){
    gui.textArea1.append("\nIOException converting: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

//the input.mp4 is in the same directory where ffmpeg.exe is. Thank you

Comment: //commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.m4v -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -vcodec mpeg4 /sdcard/videokit/vid_trans.mp4";

Comment: /sdcard/videokit/in.m4 this is your file path..

Comment: and  /sdcard/videokit/vid_trans.mp4 this is your output file path

Comment: 1. I notice you don't give path of ffmpeg.exe and my input.mp4 (input file) is located here: c:/ffmpeg/bin/input.mp4 in the root where ffmpeg.exe is located. Can you change the command to reflect that? I wish this is also so easy for me. 2. I see you have sdcard there, can we do this on a mobile phone?

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i /c:/ffmpeg/bin/input.mp4 -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -vcodec mpeg4 /c:/ffmpeg/bin/output.mp4 gives me IOException converting: Cannot run program "197": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified. What is wrong with it? Thanks:-)

Comment: how long will a 10mb video take to only scaled to widthx-1, on mobile devices?